# HDIV : option tag error

Tags: html, html-select, struts-1, hdiv

Currently, I'm integrating the last version of HDIV library in an application using struts 1.

It seems to be working well. However, in some pages, where I use the `select` tag, I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: filter    at org.hdiv.taglib.html.OptionTagHDIV.renderOptionElement(OptionTagHDIV.java:124)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.html.OptionTag.doEndTag(OptionTag.java:225)
>     at org.hdiv.taglib.html.OptionTagHDIV.doEndTag(OptionTagHDIV.java:91)

Apparently, the problem comes from the `option` tag.

My code is the following:

```
<html:select property="profilId" styleId="profileCriteria">
    <html:option value="">
    &nbsp;
    </html:option>
    <html:optionsCollection name="profilesManager" property="profiles" value="ID" label="name" />
</html:select>
```

Is there a way in HDIV to fix this error and display the `select` options?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

This simple code is not working either:

```
<html:select property="profilId" styleId="profileCriteria">
    <html:option value="1">Profile1</html:option>
    <html:option value="2">Profile2</html:option>
</html:select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you are using the correct Struts library version.
It seems you are using a Struts version HDIV doesn't support.
Gotzon Illarramendi (HDIV Team)

Comment: It took us some time to upgrade to struts 1.3.8 and now we do not have such a problem. Thanks Gotzon